# How to enable ASP Classic in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, asp

I am running IIS 7.5 in Windows 7 and have already gone into "Turn Windows features on or off" and enabled ASP  in "Internet Information Services/World Wide Web Service/application Development Features". Once I did that I started getting an HTTP 404 error saying:

```
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension 
configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be 
downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

So I took this to mean that I needed to add a mapping to *.asp in the Handler mappings and the handler is mapped to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll. But when I try to load the page I get a server error saying:

```
Could not load type 'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll'.
```

Does anyone know what is going on here or how to handle this?

Please note this is ASP Classic not ASP.NET, ASP.NET is working just fine for me.